# How to set python 3 as default interpreter in Linux

Tags: linux, alias

I have python 2.x and 3.x installed on my `Linux` box. but to run the python 3.x I have to type command `python3 <cmd>` . But i want to update the alias python to point python3 so I don't have to use python3 in command.

I tried to update the `~/.bashrc` but it does not reflect for all the the users who logged in to same `Linux`box using their own id

other option is to run this command `alias python=python3` but this has to run every time whenever I login to box. I want permanently set the alias and it should available for all the users.

Comment: The answer to this question will vary from distribution to distribution, due to the ways in which packages are installed and manged, and how that package management modified directories, paths, symbolic links and potentially environment variables. What Distribution of Linux are you running?

Comment: [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files) details what startup files are sourced and under which curcumstances. Typically, `/etc/profile` is sourced when Bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or non-interactive with the `--login` option.

Comment: Note that if you are running Wayland instead of X.Org, you might need to [edit `/etc/environment` instead](https://lwn.net/Articles/709769/) (also see https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/environment_variables).

Comment: As @JamesS. said, it depends on the distribution. In Ubuntu, there are packages called `python-is-python2` and `python-is-python3` available to install. If you install either of them, it will symlink `/usr/bin/python` to either `/usr/bin/python2` or `/usr/bin/python3`. Of course, you can create such a symlink manually without a need to install a package (on any Linux distro, and that's the simplest answer to your question), they are there just for convenience. However, if you already have `/usr/bin/python` linked to python2, I don't recommend switching it to python3 as you may break something.

Answer (score 3):

Edit:
Put your alias to /etc/bashrc (RedHat), /etc/bash.bashrc (Ubuntu) - it will be system-wide.

As per '*doneal24*' comments don't use this part of my answer below (it will break your scripts expecting/wanting python2.x under /usr/bin/python):
End of Edit

Create soft (symbolic) link instead of using aliases:

Delete current link /usr/bin/python pointing to, probably, /usr/bin/python2.x

Create new one symbolic link:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python
```

It will be system wide, so any user will get python3.x running python cmd (if he doesn't have his/her own alias differently set than this).

Comment: I don't understand why downvote? I want to learn, so please explain what wrong is with my answer. Thanks...

Comment: There may be system scripts that use the hashbang `#!/usr/bin/python` and expect this to be python2. Since python3 is not backwards compatible with python2, you may be breaking these scripts.

Comment: @doneal24, thanks... I see now. But he can then put his alias in /etc/bashrc - it will be system-wide and will not affect scripts you mention. Am I right?

Comment: A better option might be to link `/usr/local/bin/python` to `python3`. This will usually be first in the search list and does not interfere with hashbangs (unless you're using `#!/usr/bin/env python`).

Comment: @doneal24 what would be the good practise in this situation when I gave bad answer. Delete entire answer, (so it cannot mislead someone), edit it and delete bad part and provide beter info, ...

Comment: You answered the question correctly.  Whether or not this is ideal depends on the use case.